# How to get WTForms Validator in jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

What I would like to do is check what type of form validators a form object has so that I can render the field with based on those attributes. For example if the form has max-length validation then add the max-length property to the html form.

I was thinking of it working something like this:

```
zip_code = TextField('Zip Code', [validators.Length(min=5, max=11)])
```

will go to a Jinja2 macro like so:

```
{% if field.valdator "has max length" %}
  {% set class = class + ' maxlength="11" ' %}
{% endif %}
{{ field(class=class, **kwargs) }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{ form.field.validators }}` returns a list, so you can get validators by index value.

```
class ZipCodeForm(Form):
    zip_code = StringField("Zip Code", [validators.Length(3,45)])

def register():
    form = ZipCodeForm()
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

# register.html
...
 {% macro textfield(type=text, max=20) %}
     <input type={{type}}, size={{max}} >
 {% endmacro %}

 {% if form.zip_code.validators[0]["max"] %}
     textfield(max=60)
 {% endif %}
```